# Is this show of Islamic Republic and the US confrontation beneficial for Trump's impeachment process?

Tags: united-states, donald-trump, military, iran, trump-impeachment

I'm an Iranian that I'm just living in the US for a couple of years. Recently, the [tension between the US and Islamic Republic regime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2019%E2%80%9320_attack_on_the_United_States_embassy_in_Baghdad) is heightened to another level that we didn't see it before. In fact, [the US killed Soleimani in Iraq](https://www.cnn.com/2020/01/03/asia/soleimani-profile-intl-hnk/index.html) and finally, Islamic Republic regime, after several hollow threatening, [attacked a military base in Iraq](https://www.cnn.com/middleeast/live-news/us-iran-news-01-08-2020/index.html) that was occupied by the US military forces. Today, it's revealed that this attack [didn't have any human fatalities](https://www.cnn.com/2020/01/08/middleeast/iran-base-strikes-logic-intl/index.html) or in another word, no US citizen is killed in the last night attack and also Trump said he is not interested [to pursue a possible war with Islamic Republic anymore](https://www.nytimes.com/2020/01/08/world/middleeast/trump-speech.html).

This whole theater looks like a big fraud or hoax to me. I mean what was the reason behind attacking a military base in Iraq that was known that no US soldier is in there. If Islamic Republic truly wanted to retaliate the US, it could have more interesting goals to attack such as the US allies or some other military base even in the Europe to make sure the US citizens would be killed and that would be a true retaliation. Don't get it wrong! I'm not asking why they didn't do it cause I like to see it, but I'm just saying it looks like just a ridiculous circus instead of a true military conflict. You know, [conspiracy theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British%E2%80%93Ruhollah_Khomeini_conspiracy_theory) has a really deep root in our culture (remember I'm Iranian!) and it's an old theory that Islamic Republic and Ayatollahs are just the US or British sock-puppets. This ridiculous theater, that the US and Islamic Republic want us to believe that it's a true military conflict, has a really important results for both the US and Islamic Republic. In fact, you see all the news in the US is shifted toward this ridiculous attack and almost everybody forgot about impeachment of Trump, and on the other side, in Iran, almost everybody forgot about recent protests in Iran about gas price. So, it seems this big fraud is a win-win show for both Islamic Republic and the US. The last but not the least, it's that [Ukranian airplane](https://www.npr.org/2020/01/07/794430621/jetliner-reportedly-carrying-180-people-crashes-near-tehran-airport) that is crashed near Tehran that lead to death of 176 innocent people. Is it just a coincidence that we see the name of some countries in several problem around the world always such as Ukraine here and in Trump's impeachment story? So my question: Is this show could be potentially beneficial for Trump in his impeachment process?

Comment: To add to your list of occurrences: there is now some reporting that the Iranians may have warned Iraq (and thereby the US) prior to launching their missile attack, and also that Iraqi Shia cleric Muqtada al-Sadr has told his militia to "stand down".

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but [this[(https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/49241/29681) might be useful.

Comment: I'm of the opinion Iran pulled its punch so both sides can save face: they can say they "slapped the US in the face" and Trump can say "nobody died".

Comment: @TemporalWolf: Iranian TV announced some 80 US casualties, so yeah, there was definitely a different message for the internal Iranian public.

Comment: @Fizz Add to that US officials have said Iran warned Iraq (and they passed the message on)... this was symbolic, rather than tactical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Beneficial" in what way? It's within the President's powers to act as he did. Therefore there isn't anything, on the surface, about the Soleimani strike that would be impeachable.

Impeachment is, among other things, a political trial. There has never been a chance that Trump would be removed from office. It would require 20 Republican Senators to join all Democratic and Independent Senators in voting for impeachment. As of right now it's doubtful that all Democratic Senators will vote for impeachment.  Was the strike "beneficial" for Trump as far as swaying public opinion in his favor? That's too early to tell.